# fetching pinata works in dev environment but in production it does not?

Tags: nft, react, pinata, cors

I have an Nft contract and this is fetching on react.js

```
 const fetchNfts=async () => {
    const nfts = [] as Nft[];
    const onSaleNfts = await contract!.getAllNftsOnSale();
    for (let i = 0; i < onSaleNfts.length; i++) {
      const item = onSaleNfts[i];
      // debugger;
      const tokenURI = await contract!.tokenURI(item.tokenId);
      // this logs
      console.log("tokenUri is saved like this in blockchain", tokenURI);

      const metaRes = await fetch(tokenURI);

      let meta;
      try {
        meta = await metaRes.json();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error in json fetch", error);
      }

      nfts.push({
        price: parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatEther(item.price)),
        tokenId: item.tokenId.toNumber(),
        creator: item.creator,
        isListed: item.isListed,
        meta,
      });
    }
    console.log("nfts---", nfts);
    return nfts;
  }
```

this works in development:

[image]

as you see there is no error logged on console. However, I deployed the app on vercel and it does not fetch. I get CORS error:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmdXNbfAarWxsnMRmDmqTVhCAxEmvUpCyEBjjofsK2ZcFT'
> from origin
> 'https://next-js-nft-marketplace-62jdxt8cv-yilmazbingo.vercel.app' has
> been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
> is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves
> your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource
> with CORS disabled.

[image]

I do not understand what causes cors block in production.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it has some issue with the backend or server. CORS error usually comes from there.

Comment: I know cors error is server error but why it does not give me error on localhost

Answer (score 0):

This likely because you are using the Pinata Public Gateway `gateway.pinata.cloud` which are [not recommended for production use](https://docs.pinata.cloud/docs/ipfs-gateways#public-gateways). You may want to consider using a [Dedicated IPFS Gateway](https://docs.pinata.cloud/docs/dedicated-ipfs-gateways) as they are less prone to rate limiting and restrictions put on Public Gateways. They actually come with free plans now!